# trigger click event of the span tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript, click, pdftron

I'm trying to trigger click event on  tag inside the div tag.here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#span").on('click',function(e){
           console.log("clicked in link");
           
       });
 });
```

and here is the html structure (this is a PDF-tron Pdf viewer)

[image]

but , it doesn't work. How could I trigger the click event using pure Java script?

Thank you.

Comment: Element highlighted in the image doesn't have that id. Try using selector `"span.link"` Also is the pdf inside an iframe?

Comment: please don't just put a picture it is so hard to work with can we need code and error log in the consol would be good

Comment: @charlietfl, yes it's inside the iframe. these span tags are dynamic tags. generated from pdf viewer , so can't set id

Comment: @SolomonPByer , noted.. got your point.. thank you for your advice..

Comment: Iframes have their own window and `document` so you need to get those references to be able to add event listeners to elements inside. Never used that viewer but it may also have an API you can use to help out

Comment: The code here is using jquery. Can you confirm that you do not want a jquery answer?

Comment: @PaulRooney Jqueries  some times not working with vue. so I believe jquery won't help this. thanks .

Answer (score 1):

1. The issue is that span is a tag name, not an ID, so instead of `$("#span")` you should do `$("span")`, but be careful, there might be other span elements there as well.
2. "How could I trigger the click event using pure Java script?"
   The trick for PDFTron WebViewer is that it reners the document in an iFrame.
   So, to access the iframe DOM element, you can do this in the WebViewer constructor, for example:

> ```
> Webviewer(
>   {
>     /// ...
>   },
>   document.getElementById('viewer')
> ).then((instance) => {
>   instance.iframeWindow.document.querySelector('put_your_selector_here').addEventListener('click', () => {
>     console.log('clicked');
>   });
> });
> ```

Comment: it doesn't work @Oscar Zhang .. here is the span which I want to trigger click event."<span class="link" tabindex="0" style="position: absolute; font-size: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; color: inherit; width: 36.5867px; height: 43.0368px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; background-color: transparent; vertical-align: top;"></span>"

Comment: Here is the code I tried,.   WebViewer(
      {
        path: "/webviewer",
        fullAPI: true,
        annotAuthor: this.file_author,
      },
      document.getElementById("webviewer")
    ).then(async (instance) => {
        instance.iframeWindow.document.querySelector('link').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('clicked');
  });

Comment: @user3518127 You made an mistake in the querySelector:
Since "link" is an class name, you need to add a dot in front of it.
So, it should be `querySelector('.link').addEventListener....`

Comment: Also, I don't know why you want to trigger another click event on the link annotation, since link annotation already has default behaviour: open external/internal link in a new page. If you can explain what you are trying todo, maybe I can help you with a better solution.

Comment: Yea, my requirement is , I want to get page number which I clicked , for make return button . because it links to new page (master detail page) , so I wants to easily go back page which I last reviewed). that's why I trying to trigger another click event to get page number. Annotation selected event doesn't trigger it..

Comment: @user3518127 you can use this API to get the current page number: https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/Core.DocumentViewer.html#getcurrentpage

Answer (score 0):

Use [`jQuery.click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/):

```js
$("span.link").click()
```

Comment: should it run inside document ready function?

Comment: @user3518127 It should, otherwise `$('#span')` might not select the element.

Comment: I couldn't mention , i'm using vue js. is this work with vue js?

Comment: @user3518127 I updated my answer to use a different selector.

Comment: I added this to layout blade <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>  and here is the code inside vue component. $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("in.....");
       $("span.link").click(function(){
     console.log("clicked jquery");
      });
    });

Comment: or should i install jquery using npm?

Comment: <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script> at the top of the page and everything goes in the function $(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: @user3518127 WebViewer CoreControls.js is no longer dependent on jQuery since V6, if you still want to use jQuery in your project, you can refer to this guide: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/get-started/jquery/#prerequisites
And here is a sample project: https://github.com/PDFTron/webviewer-jquery-sample/blob/master/app/index.html

Answer (score 0):

@Spectric has half of the answer really

```
$("span.link").click()
```

will click on the span but you incorrectly set the click function

```
$("#span").on('click',function(e){
```

the # is for ids not for all elements. So it should be changed to

```
 $("span").on('click',function(e){
```

or better yet to be more specific like @Spectric said

```
$("span.link").on('click',function(e){
```

Comment: yes. I did same what you mentioned and no luck. here , theses tags are inside an iframe. Is this way can trigger click event for that span tags..?

Comment: yeah, you can't access things inside an iframe unless you write the code in the iframe and use cookies or something.